# Evaluate Excel Column with expression

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an excel sheet which contains many column as input. I have another sheet which contains column name with expression.

Example - The expression sheet contains

```
{{CS_RRC_Successful (number)+PS_RRC_Sucessful (number)}*100},
```

where `CS_RRC_Successful` (number) and `PS_RRC_Sucessful` (number) is column available in input sheet.

How I should evaluate these expression with `poi` using `java`?

Comment: What is 'number' in the expressions above? Is it Row number?

Answer (score 0):

The "cellType" will tell you if it a formula. Then, call getCellFormula()

```
if(theCell.getCellType()== Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA)
{
   String formulaVal = theCell.getCellFormula();
}
```

Check out the API docs to see the other formula-related methods available on a Cell. https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html

Comment: Actually this is not a cell formula. The expression sheet which contains {{CS_RRC_Successful (number)+PS_RRC_Sucessful (number)}*100}, here  CS_RRC_Successful (number) and PS_RRC_Sucessful (number) is column which is available on another sheet. The column name can change dynamic, So, based on expression I have to search column in input sheet and the calculate the. In the above column, after search in input sheet, both column value will add and the multiply with 100.

Comment: Why not make it into a Formula then?

Comment: If I understand you right, you're saying it is a string as far as Excel is concerned. But, when you see something like "CS_RRC_Successful " what does this mean? Is this a header column in the input sheet or is it an Excel range in the input sheet?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sample code that evaluates the formula - `SUM(A1:B1)+10` for a cell. You will have to replace it with the formula you are using and set the cell type to Numeric (or whichever data type your excel formula will return).

See below example:

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator(); 
//you will need to create the row in case you are making a new file.    
Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
Cell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
//set cell formula
cell2.setCellFormula("SUM(A1:B1)+10");
//evaluate the formula
evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell2);
//set the cell type to numeric
cell2.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);   //or CELL_TYPE_FORMULA
System.out.println(cell2.getNumericCellValue());

//write data to excel file
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("res/Book1.xlsx"));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();
System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");
```

Comment: Why are you setting the cell type to numeric at the end? For a formula cell, just fetching the numeric value will work fine for a number-producing formula after evaluation

Comment: At times the cell shows a `Value#` error on the Cell's top right corner, after you write the file and open it. To avoid that I set it as Numeric. (Just for the display).

Comment: I have not the column reference as you have written Sum(A1:B1)+10, I have the column header in formula as I have written in my question, and on the base of column header I have to process multiple row which present in input sheet.

Comment: What is the formula you have so far? Please edit your question and specify the formula you are trying to evaluate and what you are trying to do.